# Excel vba Finance number clearence

Tags: excel, vba, formula

So, I am working for the finance team. My main job is to find if the outcome equals the income. There is a column in an excel sheet which has number both -ve and +ve what i want to do is to delete each one with anthor to get a 0 and if there will be no zeros i want the extra ones.
So, if i have a list containing 5,-2,-3,-7,5,2,1,9 i want it to hide all rows but 1 and 9 but of course, with a column of 5000 rows and bigger numbers it is really hard task even after removing duplicated numbers like 5,-5 the remaining will be about 4000. if it is impossible with vba will formula do any better ?
thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't you also want -3 and -7?

Comment: No because 5 , -2  , -3 will clear each others -7 , 5 , 2 will clear each others too and 1 , 9  will appear only

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 helper columns. Assuming data is in A. B1=`=ABS(A1)` and C1=`=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B1)>1,"",A1)`. Fill both of them down.

Comment: oh , i just understand what you did. No, what i really need is not removing things like duplication -ve & +ve but if 2 - ve numbers build up to make 1 +ve so they clear each others

Comment: Ah that would need a VBA loop through everything. Is it always a pairing of 2 and 1 that cancel? And are they always sequential? Like in your example. Or could it be -2,5,-3

Comment: There is no sequentials and no not pairing of 2 and 1

Comment: Sorry my friend but then I am not following the problem/what help is needed. Maybe someone else can!